# Access OneDrive images from web application

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I want to display a multi-folder gallery of our publicly available photos held on OneDrive in conjunction with filename-keyed text (captions, descriptions, etc) currently held on a MySql DB. There seemed two possible approaches:

- Launch OneDrive's viewer from a companion JavaScript document and use their document title (contains the filename), to display the details in an 'always-on-top' window. Problem: not sure if its possible to access the title.
- Alternative solution: extract and store OneDrive's file "paths" and use these to feed a separate gallery app. Unfortunately, these tags seem to be time limited. Clearly in an application like this, I can't expect casual users to log in.

Doing my head in here and seemingly frustrated at every turn! Anyone got any ideas how it could be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

You should do some research and learn how to interface with One Drive's official API.

https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm

Ideally you'd be able to use their own API to query for the data you need. They even have a [JavaScript file picker SDK](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/javascript-picker-saver.htm).

Comment: Thanks Chev. Did create a functional Php xaction to extract temporary paths from onedrive,  but was left with the impression that it wld be necessary to sign in to do this in real time. (Not possible in this case). Was I right?